compiling error for gcc-14.1.0 on Ubuntu 22.04
I tried to build gcc-14.1.0 with following steps but have an error with 'make'
sudo apt install build-essential
sudo apt install libmpfr-dev libgmp3-dev libmpc-dev -y
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-14.1.0/gcc-14.1.0.tar.gz
tar -xf gcc-14.1.0.tar.gz
cd gcc-14.1.0
./configure -v --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-14.1.0 --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --program-suffix=-14.1.0
make
x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -std=c++11 -c   -g -DIN_GCC    -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-format -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wconditionally-supported -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -DGENERATOR_FILE -I. -Ibuild -I../.././gcc -I../.././gcc/build -I../.././gcc/../include  -I../.././gcc/../libcpp/include  
-o build/genmodes.o ../.././gcc/genmodes.cc
In file included from ./bconfig.h:3,
from ../.././gcc/genmodes.cc:20:
./auto-host.h:2748:16: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
2748 | #define rlim_t long
 |                ^~~~

make[3]: *** [Makefile:2997: build/genmodes.o] Error 1
